# ipyparallel Hub Connection Timeout with parallel CV in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ipython-parallel, joblib

I am trying to train multiple RandomForest classifiers using ipyparallel. My design is nested CV loops outer CV with for remove variance, inner GridSearchCV with built in (`n_jobs = -1`) to find the best estimators (# forests, #trees in Forest) for the RandomForest and to train each combination (fit function) with ipyparallel with sge (training the Forest is the inner most step).

If I run GridSearchCV with `n_jobs = 1`, everything runs smoothly, and slowly. 
But if I make `n_jobs > 1`, after the first iteration (very fast) of the outer CV loop, I get a HubConnectionTimeout error.

I have attached code with this. And the error.

CV Loops:

```
kf = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(Y, n_folds=k, shuffle=shuffle)
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
        rusCV = GridSearchCV(RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=100, n_TreesInForest=300), tune_params, cv=20, n_jobs = -1)
        # do work
```

ipyparallel : 
(fit in RUSRandomForestClassifier) - called by GridSearchCV from above

```
c = Client(profile='sge', timeout=300)
view = c.direct_view()
forests = view.map_async(__trainForest, dataTupleList)
forests.get()
c.purge_everything()
c.close(linger=True)
```

Error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 130, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py", line 43, in fit
    self.trainJungle(X, Y)
  File "/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py", line 46, in trainJungle
    c = Client(url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', timeout=300)
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py", line 478, in __init__
    self._connect(sshserver, ssh_kwargs, timeout)
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py", line 598, in _connect
    raise error.TimeoutError("Hub connection request timed out")
ipyparallel.error.TimeoutError: Hub connection request timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 143, in __call__
    raise TransportableException(text, e_type)
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.TransportableException: TransportableException
___________________________________________________________________________
TimeoutError                                       Mon Feb 15 13:29:45 2016
PID: 30122                Python 3.4.4: /home/sulantha/anaconda3/bin/python

...........................................................................

/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py in fit(self=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), Y=array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0]))
     38         return finalRUSX, finalRUSY
     39 
     40 
     41 
     42     def fit(self, X, Y):
---> 43         self.trainJungle(X, Y)
        self.trainJungle = <bound method RUSRandomForestClassifier.trainJun...restClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50)>
        X = array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]])
        Y = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
     44 
     45     def trainJungle(self, X, Y):
     46         c = Client(url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', timeout=300)
     47         view = c.direct_view()

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py in trainJungle(self=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), Y=array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0]))
     41 
     42     def fit(self, X, Y):
     43         self.trainJungle(X, Y)
     44 
     45     def trainJungle(self, X, Y):
---> 46         c = Client(url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', timeout=300)
        c = undefined
     47         view = c.direct_view()
     48         def __trainForest(xyTuple):
     49             (X, Y) = xyTuple
     50             rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=self.n_TreesInForest, verbose=0, class_weight='auto')

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in __init__(self=<ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>, url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', ipython_dir=None, context=<zmq.sugar.context.Context object>, debug=False, sshserver='', sshkey=None, password=None, paramiko=None, timeout=300, cluster_id=None, **extra_args={'key': b'3bf859ee-882a-4929-882a-be1edaa9e0c9', 'packer': 'json', 'signature_scheme': 'hmac-sha256', 'unpacker': 'json'})
    473                                     }
    474         self._queue_handlers = {'execute_reply' : self._handle_execute_reply,
    475                                 'apply_reply' : self._handle_apply_reply}
    476         
    477         try:
--> 478             self._connect(sshserver, ssh_kwargs, timeout)
        self._connect = <bound method Client._connect of <ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>>
        sshserver = ''
        ssh_kwargs = {'keyfile': None, 'paramiko': None, 'password': None}
        timeout = 300
    479         except:
    480             self.close(linger=0)
    481             raise
    482         

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in _connect(self=<ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>, sshserver='', ssh_kwargs={'keyfile': None, 'paramiko': None, 'password': None}, timeout=300)
    593         poller = zmq.Poller()
    594         poller.register(self._query_socket, zmq.POLLIN)
    595         # poll expects milliseconds, timeout is seconds
    596         evts = poller.poll(timeout*1000)
    597         if not evts:
--> 598             raise error.TimeoutError("Hub connection request timed out")
    599         idents,msg = self.session.recv(self._query_socket,mode=0)
    600         if self.debug:
    601             pprint(msg)
    602         content = msg['content']

TimeoutError: Hub connection request timed out
___________________________________________________________________________
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 731, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get())
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.TransportableException: TransportableException
___________________________________________________________________________
TimeoutError                                       Mon Feb 15 13:29:45 2016
PID: 30122                Python 3.4.4: /home/sulantha/anaconda3/bin/python
...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
     67     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
     68         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
     69         self._size = len(self.items)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        self.items = [(<function _fit_and_score>, (RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), array([[ 82.15616438,   1.        ,   0.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), <function _passthrough_scorer>, array([  9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  ..., 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), 0, {'n_Forests': 10, 'n_TreesInForest': 50}, {}), {'error_score': 'raise', 'return_parameters': True})]
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):
     75         return self._size
     76 

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
     67     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
     68         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
     69         self._size = len(self.items)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        func = <function _fit_and_score>
        args = (RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), array([[ 82.15616438,   1.        ,   0.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), <function _passthrough_scorer>, array([  9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  ..., 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), 0, {'n_Forests': 10, 'n_TreesInForest': 50}, {})
        kwargs = {'error_score': 'raise', 'return_parameters': True}
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):
     75         return self._size
     76 

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 82.15616438,   1.        ,   0.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), y=array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), scorer=<function _passthrough_scorer>, train=array([  9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  ..., 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171]), test=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), verbose=0, parameters={'n_Forests': 10, 'n_TreesInForest': 50}, fit_params={}, return_train_score=False, return_parameters=True, error_score='raise')
   1526 
   1527     try:
   1528         if y_train is None:
   1529             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
   1530         else:
-> 1531             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
        estimator.fit = <bound method RUSRandomForestClassifier.fit of R...restClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50)>
        X_train = array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]])
        y_train = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
        fit_params = {}
   1532 
   1533     except Exception as e:
   1534         if error_score == 'raise':
   1535             raise

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py in fit(self=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), Y=array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0]))
     38         return finalRUSX, finalRUSY
     39 
     40 
     41 
     42     def fit(self, X, Y):
---> 43         self.trainJungle(X, Y)
        self.trainJungle = <bound method RUSRandomForestClassifier.trainJun...restClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50)>
        X = array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]])
        Y = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
     44 
     45     def trainJungle(self, X, Y):
     46         c = Client(url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', timeout=300)
     47         view = c.direct_view()

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py in trainJungle(self=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), Y=array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0]))
     41 
     42     def fit(self, X, Y):
     43         self.trainJungle(X, Y)
     44 
     45     def trainJungle(self, X, Y):
---> 46         c = Client(url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', timeout=300)
        c = undefined
     47         view = c.direct_view()
     48         def __trainForest(xyTuple):
     49             (X, Y) = xyTuple
     50             rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=self.n_TreesInForest, verbose=0, class_weight='auto')

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in __init__(self=<ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>, url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', ipython_dir=None, context=<zmq.sugar.context.Context object>, debug=False, sshserver='', sshkey=None, password=None, paramiko=None, timeout=300, cluster_id=None, **extra_args={'key': b'3bf859ee-882a-4929-882a-be1edaa9e0c9', 'packer': 'json', 'signature_scheme': 'hmac-sha256', 'unpacker': 'json'})
    473                                     }
    474         self._queue_handlers = {'execute_reply' : self._handle_execute_reply,
    475                                 'apply_reply' : self._handle_apply_reply}
    476         
    477         try:
--> 478             self._connect(sshserver, ssh_kwargs, timeout)
        self._connect = <bound method Client._connect of <ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>>
        sshserver = ''
        ssh_kwargs = {'keyfile': None, 'paramiko': None, 'password': None}
        timeout = 300
    479         except:
    480             self.close(linger=0)
    481             raise
    482         

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in _connect(self=<ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>, sshserver='', ssh_kwargs={'keyfile': None, 'paramiko': None, 'password': None}, timeout=300)
    593         poller = zmq.Poller()
    594         poller.register(self._query_socket, zmq.POLLIN)
    595         # poll expects milliseconds, timeout is seconds
    596         evts = poller.poll(timeout*1000)
    597         if not evts:
--> 598             raise error.TimeoutError("Hub connection request timed out")
    599         idents,msg = self.session.recv(self._query_socket,mode=0)
    600         if self.debug:
    601             pprint(msg)
    602         content = msg['content']

TimeoutError: Hub connection request timed out
___________________________________________________________________________

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/runClassificationHAI2016.py", line 191, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/runClassificationHAI2016.py", line 163, in main
    result = doRUSRFC(itemList[0])
  File "/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/runClassificationHAI2016.py", line 77, in doRUSRFC
    shuffle=True, print_v=True, k=10, tune_params=tune_params, ext_x_test=analysisDict['X_test'])
  File "/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/runClassificationHAI2016.py", line 44, in CVJungle
    rusCV.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 804, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 553, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 812, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 762, in retrieve
    raise exception
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibTimeoutError: JoblibTimeoutError
___________________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub-process traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                                       Mon Feb 15 13:29:45 2016
PID: 30122                Python 3.4.4: /home/sulantha/anaconda3/bin/python
...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
     67     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
     68         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
     69         self._size = len(self.items)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        self.items = [(<function _fit_and_score>, (RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), array([[ 82.15616438,   1.        ,   0.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), <function _passthrough_scorer>, array([  9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  ..., 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), 0, {'n_Forests': 10, 'n_TreesInForest': 50}, {}), {'error_score': 'raise', 'return_parameters': True})]
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):
     75         return self._size
     76 

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
     67     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
     68         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
     69         self._size = len(self.items)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        func = <function _fit_and_score>
        args = (RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), array([[ 82.15616438,   1.        ,   0.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), <function _passthrough_scorer>, array([  9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  ..., 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), 0, {'n_Forests': 10, 'n_TreesInForest': 50}, {})
        kwargs = {'error_score': 'raise', 'return_parameters': True}
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):
     75         return self._size
     76 

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 82.15616438,   1.        ,   0.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), y=array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), scorer=<function _passthrough_scorer>, train=array([  9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  ..., 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171]), test=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), verbose=0, parameters={'n_Forests': 10, 'n_TreesInForest': 50}, fit_params={}, return_train_score=False, return_parameters=True, error_score='raise')
   1526 
   1527     try:
   1528         if y_train is None:
   1529             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
   1530         else:
-> 1531             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
        estimator.fit = <bound method RUSRandomForestClassifier.fit of R...restClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50)>
        X_train = array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]])
        y_train = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
        fit_params = {}
   1532 
   1533     except Exception as e:
   1534         if error_score == 'raise':
   1535             raise

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/PycharmProjects/TwoStepArticle/Python/RUSRandomForest/RUSRandomForestClassifier.py in fit(self=RUSRandomForestClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50), X=array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]]), Y=array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0]))
     38         return finalRUSX, finalRUSY
     39 
     40 
     41 
     42     def fit(self, X, Y):
---> 43         self.trainJungle(X, Y)
        self.trainJungle = <bound method RUSRandomForestClassifier.trainJun...restClassifier(n_Forests=10, n_TreesInForest=50)>
        X = array([[ 66.14246575,   2.        ,   1.        ...1.63758022,
          1.44694768,   1.36380531]])
        Y = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
     44 
     45     def trainJungle(self, X, Y):
     46         c = Client(url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', timeout=300)
     47         view = c.direct_view()

...........................................................................

/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in __init__(self=<ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>, url_file='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/security/ipcontroller-client.json', profile='sge', profile_dir='/home/sulantha/.ipython/profile_sge/', ipython_dir=None, context=<zmq.sugar.context.Context object>, debug=False, sshserver='', sshkey=None, password=None, paramiko=None, timeout=300, cluster_id=None, **extra_args={'key': b'3bf859ee-882a-4929-882a-be1edaa9e0c9', 'packer': 'json', 'signature_scheme': 'hmac-sha256', 'unpacker': 'json'})
    473                                     }
    474         self._queue_handlers = {'execute_reply' : self._handle_execute_reply,
    475                                 'apply_reply' : self._handle_apply_reply}
    476         
    477         try:
--> 478             self._connect(sshserver, ssh_kwargs, timeout)
        self._connect = <bound method Client._connect of <ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>>
        sshserver = ''
        ssh_kwargs = {'keyfile': None, 'paramiko': None, 'password': None}
        timeout = 300
    479         except:
    480             self.close(linger=0)
    481             raise
    482         

...........................................................................
/home/sulantha/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in _connect(self=<ipyparallel.client.client.Client object>, sshserver='', ssh_kwargs={'keyfile': None, 'paramiko': None, 'password': None}, timeout=300)
    593         poller = zmq.Poller()
    594         poller.register(self._query_socket, zmq.POLLIN)
    595         # poll expects milliseconds, timeout is seconds
    596         evts = poller.poll(timeout*1000)
    597         if not evts:
--> 598             raise error.TimeoutError("Hub connection request timed out")
    599         idents,msg = self.session.recv(self._query_socket,mode=0)
    600         if self.debug:
    601             pprint(msg)
    602         content = msg['content']

TimeoutError: Hub connection request timed out
    ___________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

The [scikit-learn tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html) states that

> **Warning**: You cannot nest objects with parallel computing (`n_jobs` different than 1).

so it seems that all parallelization has to happen in the outer loop.